# How do I convert this java array into xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays

Background:
For my Android app, I am using a ListView and the list items trigger sounds, that are stored as .ogg files in the /res/raw/ directory. I was able to automatically set the text labels and length of the listview through string-arrays stored in strings.xml, now I need an additional array of ResIDs that I would like to store there as well for convenient expansion of the listview in the future.

Working code:
For the string arrays, I use this code:
Java Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listoftitles);
```

XML (strings.xml):

```
<string-array name="listoftitles">
    <item>Title1</item>
    <item>Title2</item>
</string-array>
```

Problematic code:
Java Fragment:

```
filenames = new int[]{R.raw.both1, R.raw.both2, R.raw.both3, R.raw.both4, R.raw.both5
            , R.raw.both6, R.raw.both7, R.raw.both8, R.raw.both9, R.raw.both10, R.raw.both11
            , R.raw.both12, R.raw.both13, R.raw.both14, R.raw.both15, R.raw.both16, R.raw.both17
            , R.raw.both18, R.raw.both19};
```

Target:

```
private void populatemylist() {
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        itemsdb.add(new Item(titles[i], descriptions[i], filenames[i]));
    }

}
```

The convenience of the method populatemylist() is crucial and while titles[] and descriptions[] are easily fetched from the xml arrays, it does not work for the filenames, which I need as a ResID / int value. I tried using an integer-array, as well as a generic array with a TypedArray Java backend, but this seems to be targeted towards drawables and I just can't get it to fetch anything from the /res/raw/ folder. I would like to have a simple array solution, that goes in the strings.xml in the fashion of

```
<item>R.raw.both1</item>
```

and a simple java backend, that gets me an int array of those filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use TypedArray, let me know if you have any problems otherwise goodluck!

filenames.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
       <string-array name="random_imgs">
        <item>@raw/both1</item>
        <item>@raw/both2</item>
        <!-- ... -->
    </string-array>

</resources>

private int getFileNameAtIndex(int index) {
        TypedArray fileNames = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.filenames);
        // or set you ImageView's resource to the id
        int id = fileNames.getResourceId(index, -1); //-1 is default if nothing is found (we don't care)
        fileNames.recycle();
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly, what I needed. All other stackoverflow questions and tutorials always used a local int[] in the Fragment and tried to cast the entire array over. This works great, as it gets only the important current value through a method, which is what all other not-working solutions were missing.